# How to return large amount of rows from mongodb using node.js http server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, http, bigdata

I have a user database in mongodb which I would like to export via a REST interface in JSON. The problem is that in the worst case scenario the amount of returned rows is well over 2 million.

First I tried this

```js
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
  Server = mongo.Server,
  Db = mongo.Db;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
var db = new Db('tracking', server);
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}, function(err, cursor){
      cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
        output = '{"users" : ' + JSON.stringify(items) + '}';

        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.end(output);
      });
    });
  });
}).listen(8008);
console.log('Server running at localhost:8008');
```

which fails when running out of memory. The example uses node-mongodb-native driver and the basic http package.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

(note that in real scenario I use parameters which limit the results as needed, but this example queries them all which is the worst case scenario regardless)

The data itself is simple, like

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f993d1c5656d3320851aadb"), "userid" : "80ec39f7-37e2-4b13-b442-6bea57472537", "user-agent" : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)", "ip" : "127.0.0.1", "lastupdate" : 1335442716 }

I also tried something like

```js
while(cursor != null)
{
  cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(item));
  });
}
```

but that ran out of memory too.

How should I proceed? There should be a way to stream the data row by row, but I haven't been able to find a suitable example for it. Paging the data is out of the question because of external application requirements. I thought of writing the data to a file and then posting it, but that leads to unwanted io.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `cursor.streamRecords()` method of the native `MongoDB` driver is deprecated, 
the method `stream()` is faster.

I have parsed a 40,000,000 row document of acatalog without problems with `Mongodb` + `stream()` + `process.nextTick()`

Comment: I found that `cursor.stream()` performs exactly the same as `cursor.each()`.

Comment: Be sure to specify a value for the `batchSize` for thousands or millions of rows

Comment: @sha0Coder how big was the amount of time for the whole parsing?

Comment: @sha0Coder is there a gist you can post about how it was done ?

Answer (score 9):

I found out that node-mongodb-native Cursor object has a streaming option (used with `collection.find().streamRecords()`) for the records too even if it's not mentioned in the [github page of the driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). See the [Cursor source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/cursor.js) and search for "streamRecords".

In the end the code ended up like this:

```js
db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
  var first = true;

  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  response.write('{"users" : [');

  var stream = collection.find().streamRecords();

  stream.on('data', function(item) {
    var prefix = first ? '' : ', ';
    response.write(prefix + JSON.stringify(item));
    first = false;
  });
  stream.on('end', function() {
    response.write(']}');
    response.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey @Timo, is there any way we can process streamed data in batches of 1000 from a dataset of over 100000.

Answer (score 5):

Something like that **should** work. If it doesn't you should probably open an issue in the [mongodb-native bug tracker](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues).

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}, function(err, cursor){
      response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      cursor.each(function(err, item) {
        if (item) {
          response.write(JSON.stringify(item));
        } else {
          response.end();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}).listen(8008);
```

PS: it's just a stub, i mean i dont remember the exact syntax, but it's `each` function you're looking for.

Comment: Actually I tried that too, but it seems that `toArray` function in my original question actually wraps/uses that `each` function, so it failed when the script ran out of memory too.

Comment: Yes, toArray needs to buffer the entire array, so that won't help, but cursor.each will work. You just need to surround it with brackets.

Comment: Now that I tried this again it works too. For some reason it failed before and I have to back and check what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I no longer use mongodb native javascript driver, but in [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/querystream.html) there is pretty good implementation of streams.

The syntax of the two drivers is pretty similar. You can do this with mongoose :

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var stream = collection.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function(doc) {
   response.write(doc);  
});
stream.on('close', function() {
   response.end();
});
```

Comment: Mongoose would be a better way to address the data storage thing altogether. Your answer lead me to right direction when using just this driver and I found out that node-mongodb-native has a streaming option too in Cursor called `streamResults`. I'll post a complete answer on my problem using just the node-mongodb-native later on.

Answer (score 2):

A little module to do that using Node's [`stream.Transform`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) class:

```
var stream = require('stream');

function createCursorStream(){

    var cursorStream = new stream.Transform({objectMode:true});

    cursorStream._transform = function(chunk,encoding,done){
        if(cursorStream.started){
            cursorStream.push(', ' + JSON.stringify(chunk));
        }else{
            cursorStream.push('[' + JSON.stringify(chunk));
            cursorStream.started = true;
        }
        done();
    };

    cursorStream._flush = function(done){
        cursorStream.push(']');
        done();
    };

    return cursorStream;
}

module.exports.streamCursorToResponse = function(cursor,response){
    cursor.stream().pipe(createCursorStream()).pipe(response);
};
```

You can alter `JSON.Stringify` parts to do any other kind of "on the fly" transforms on the objects coming from mongodb cursor, and save some memory.